# Is it possible isolate a variable thats on one side of the equation multiplying and dividing, and it's also on the other side

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I dont expect the answear, I just want to know if it's possible, and if it is, if it's theres a method for it.

Heres the equation. My goal is to isolate $\lambda$.

$$\frac{\eta}{\lambda} \frac{1}{v} (\epsilon - w) \left[\frac{\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma - (1-s_r)(\rho \delta) - s_r i \lambda }{X - \beta} \right] =  \frac{X(\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma) - \beta[(1-s_r)\rho \delta + s_r i \lambda]}{X - \beta}$$

Being $X = \dfrac{[1 - (1-s_r)\rho h - \varphi (1-h) - \eta (\epsilon - w)]}{v}$

I know it may be hard. But is it possible?

I've tried to isolate, but I ends up having a $\lambda ^2$ on one side, which makes it impossible to isolate, since theres singles $\lambda$ too.

I'm stuck at this part (left side) $\lambda v [ X(\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma - \beta [(1-s_r)\rho \delta - s_r i \lambda] + \eta (\epsilon - w) s_r i] $

Notice how theres one inside the [] that I can't get out, therefore I'm not able to isolate.

Any help is much appreciated.

Tag recommendation will also de welcomed. Not sure where to post this exactly.

Comment: "*ends up having a $\lambda^2$ on one side*" $\;-\;$ Right, the equation is a quadratic in $\lambda$, which you can then solve for $\lambda$ using the quadratic formula.

Comment: You can substitute some terms. For instance $a_1=\frac{\eta}{v}  (\epsilon - w)$. Such substitutions makes it easier to keep the overview. Show what you have tried.

Comment: @dxiv Not sure how to use that for letters. I understand i can solve for numbers. Do you have an example (youtube video, posts)?

Comment: @callculus42 not sure how much that will help. It will make it simple, of course, but I need to isolate the $\lambda$.

One part of the solution I got stuck was this one (left side) $\lambda v [ X(\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma - \beta [(1-s_r)\rho \delta - s_r i \lambda] + \eta (\epsilon - w) s_r i]$

Comment: @Alexander Collect the terms in powers of $\lambda$ and you'll end up with something like $A\lambda^2+B\lambda+C=0$ where $A,B,C$ are expressions in the other variables. Then apply the quadratic formula and solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: @Alexander Also, if you know that some of the variables are assumed to be real, then you should definitely specify that in the question, since it can make a big difference in how to proceed.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, I see now. Thank you. I'm gonna try that

and yea, lambda can't be negative (no variable there can), so the solution has to be real

Comment: @Alexander Saying that all variables are non-negative would imply they are real. In that case just equate the real and imaginary parts on the two sides of the equation. That's assuming the $"i"$ in the equation is the imaginary unit, of course.

Comment: @dxiv Oh, sorry. No. i stand for interest rate. Thats an economics model i'm trying to solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With OP's clarification that all quantities are real and $\,i\,$ is a variable, not the imaginary unit, let $\mu = s_r i \lambda$, $a = \dfrac{s_r i\eta}{v}$, $b=\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma$, $c=(1-s_r)\rho \delta$, then the equation can be written as:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\frac{s_r i}{s_r i}}\frac{\eta}{\lambda} \frac{\epsilon - w}{v} \frac{\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma - (1-s_r)\rho \delta - s_r i \lambda }{\cancel{X - \beta}} &=  \frac{X(\alpha + \tau h - \theta \gamma) - \beta\left((1-s_r)\rho \delta + s_r i \lambda\right)}{\cancel{X - \beta}}
\\ \iff\quad\quad \frac{a}{\mu}\left(b-c-\mu\right) &= bX-\beta(c + \mu)
\\ ab - a c - a\mu &= bX\mu -\beta c\mu -\beta\mu^2
\\ \underbrace{\beta}_{A} \mu^2 - \underbrace{(bX - \beta c + a)}_{B}\mu + \underbrace{ab - ac}_{C} &= 0
\end{align}
$$

The latter is a quadratic equation of the form $A\mu^2 - B\mu+C=0$ which can be solved for $\mu$ with the roots being $\mu_{1,2}=\dfrac{B \pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$, then reversing the substitution $\lambda_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{s_r i} \mu_{1,2}\,$.

Comment: Thank you, @dxiv. The answer I found is probably the same, but more confusing $ \lambda^* = \frac{-v (X J - \beta (1-s_r)\rho \delta + m s_r i) \pm \sqrt{[v (X J - \beta (1-s_r) \rho \delta + m s_r i)]^2 - 4 \beta s_r i v [m(J - (1-s_r)\rho \delta)]}}{2 \beta s_r i v}$